# PyQt4: initialize and delete QApplication instances many times

Tags: pyqt4

Is it possible to initialize and delete `QApplication` instances many times?

The following is a sample code:

```
while some_condition:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    some_actions

    del app
```

I tried, but it seemed impossible.

If I want to initialize and delete `QApplication` instances many times in a single file, how can I do that?

**UPDATE**

Here I want to use `QtWebKit` to crawl some web pages and it could parse AJAX automatically. But when I used `QApplication(sys.argv).exec_()` to start the event loop, I couldn't add new urls in the code because it entered a loop. So I think, if I could initialize and delete the  class many times, then I could add new urls to crawl. But it failed. I don't understand that why the event loop seemed still exist even after I delete the instance.

When I use `QApplication(sys).processEvents()`, I find these problems could be solved properly.

Sorry for my poor expression.

Comment: You could maybe call `app.quit()` instead of `del app`. I'm curious though, why are you doing this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @GaryHughes If I call `app.quit()`, the program will terminate. I just want to use a PyQt4 object many times. Thanks anyway. I find the solution. Instead of using `QApplication(sys.argv).exec_()`, using `QApplication(sys.argv).processEvents()` is a better practice and then I can control then event loop.

Comment: Is that in addition to creating the `app` object? That would mean you had two `QApplication` instances, which goes against what is written in the docs. Maybe `app.processEvents()` is all you need? I'm still not sure what you're trying to actually do, but something doesn't seem right here.

Comment: @GaryHughes Sorry. I updated my problem and explained why I asked such a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QApplication(sys.argv).processEvents()` instead of `QApplication(sys.argv).exec_()`

Comment: If this answer solved your problems, please accept it. Thanks!